# Is $\mathbb{Z}[i]/\langle 2+i\rangle$ a simple extension of $\mathbb{Z}_5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, extension-field

I guess that  $\mathbb{Z}[i]/\langle 2+i\rangle$ is equal to $\mathbb{Z}_5[i]$ if it is a simple extension of $\mathbb{Z}_5$. Based on this thought, I tried to construct a surjective ring homomorphism $\varphi$ from $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ to $\mathbb{Z}_5[i]$ with a kernel $\langle 2+i\rangle$. I know that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a Euclidean domain, so it makes sense for me to think $\varphi(z)$ as the "remainder" when $z$ is divided by $2+i$. But how can I express the map $\varphi$ explicitly? Thanks.

Comment: Note that $2^2=-1\bmod5$, so ${\bf Z}_5[i]={\bf Z}_5$.

Comment: Do you mean this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can write $\mathbb{Z}[i]/ \langle 2+i \rangle$ as $\mathbb{Z}[x]/ \langle x^2+1, x+2 \rangle$. As you've noted, the ideal $\langle x^2+1, x+2 \rangle$ actually contains the ideal $\langle x^2+1, 5 \rangle$ since $ (2+x)(2-x)=4-x^2=5$.

Thus, we have $\mathbb{Z}[x]/ \langle x^2+1, 2+x \rangle = \mathbb{Z}/5 \mathbb{Z}[x]/ \langle x^2+1, 2+x \rangle$. Now lets examine what the ring $ \mathbb{Z}/5 \mathbb{Z}[x]/ \langle x^2+1 \rangle$ looks like.

Modulo $5$,  $x^2+1=(x+2)(x+3)$ 
so by Chinese remainder theorem, we have $ \mathbb{Z}/5 \mathbb{Z}[x]/ \langle x^2+1 \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}/ 5 \mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x+2 \rangle \times \mathbb{Z}/ 5 \mathbb{Z}[x]/ \langle x+3 \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}/ 5 \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/ 5 \mathbb{Z}$.

Finally, if we quotient by $x+2$ then we see that this keeps the first factor unchanged but take the second factor to $0$. Thus, in conclusion we see that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/ \langle x^2+1, x+2 \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}/5 \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Should I say that $\mathbb{Z}[i]/\langle 2+i\rangle$ is not a simple extension of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ or it is a simple extension of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ as $\mathbb{Z}_5[1]$?

Comment: I guess in some sense it is the degree 1 simple extension!